# Array of objects to draw on canvas

Tags: java, android, drawing

I have an array of objects that need to be drawn to a canvas; each object is represented as:
scatterPlot.java

```
package scatter.plot;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.view.View;

public class scatterPoint extends View {
    private final Point coordinates;
    private final int itemShape;
    private Paint itemColour = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    private scatterPoint[] mShapes;

    public scatterPoint(Context context, Point p, int shape, Paint colour) { // Constructor
        super(context);
        coordinates = p;
        itemShape = shape;
        itemColour = colour;
    }

    //get set points

    public void setPoints(scatterPoint[] p){
        mShapes = p;
    }

    public scatterPoint[] getScatterPoints(){
        return mShapes;
    }

     @Override
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         //super.onDraw(canvas);

         int radius = 10;
         for (scatterPoint i : mShapes) {
             switch(itemShape){
                 case 0:
                     canvas.drawRect(i.coordinates.x - radius, i.coordinates.y - radius, i.coordinates.x + radius, i.coordinates.y + radius, i.itemColour);
                     break;
                 case 1:
                     Path path = new Path();
                     path.moveTo(i.coordinates.x - radius, i.coordinates.y - radius);
                     path.lineTo(i.coordinates.x, i.coordinates.y + radius);
                     path.lineTo(i.coordinates.x + radius, i.coordinates.y - radius);
                     path.lineTo(i.coordinates.x - radius, i.coordinates.y - radius);
                     path.close();

                     canvas.drawPath(path, i.itemColour);
                     break;
                 case 2:
                     canvas.drawCircle(i.coordinates.x, i.coordinates.y, radius, i.itemColour);
                     break;
             }
         }
     }

    public Point getCoordinates(){
        return coordinates;
    }

    public int getShape(){
        return itemShape;
    }

    public Paint getColour(){
        return itemColour;
    }
}
```

Relevant methods from main (ScatterPlotActivity.java):

```
package scatter.plot;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class ScatterPlotActivity extends Activity {
    FrameLayout main;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        main = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);

        scatterPoint[] points = generatePoints();

        //
        //add scatterPoint to main
        //
    }
    public scatterPoint[] generatePoints(){
    //
    return points;
    }

}
```

Any ideas on what is wrong with how I'm trying to draw these objects?

Comment: Have you checked the value of `points.length`?

Comment: Yes, I set it to 20. The points are randomly generated in the main class and are all valid.

Comment: What layoutparams do these View-derived classes have?

Comment: In the XML?
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
I also added a few to onCreate in main:
    `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the fact that you're creating each time a new `FrameLayout`. Declare your `FrameLayout` in your main and then call your method `drawPoints` like this:

```
drawPoint(points[i], main);
```

and your method will look like this :

```
public void drawPoint(scatterPoint point, FrameLayout main) {
    main.addView(point);
}
```

This way they will always be added to the same Layout.

Comment: The FrameLayout is always there. It is created when the activity sets it as its content view. He is just using an expensive method of finding an already created view instead of just keeping the reference. (!!!No longer applicable since the edit.!!!)

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of things, you are actually drawing all of your scatter point views. However, due to how you are adding them to the FrameLayout, they are stacking on top of each other. Look in your drawPoint() method. You add the point to FrameLayout, which was designed to only handle one view (for more on this statement refer to [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html#generateDefaultLayoutParams%28%29)), and the FrameLayout just draws the new view right over the last view drawn.

```
class ScatterShape {
    public float mX = 0, mY = 0;
    public int mShape = 0;
    public Paint mColor = new Paint();

    public ScatterShape(float x, float y, int shape, int color) {
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        mShape = shape;
        mColor.setColor(color);
    }
}


public class ScatterShaperDrawer extends View {
    private List<ScatterShape> mShapes = new ArrayList<ScatterShapes>();
    private float mmRadius = 5;

    // Make getter and setter

    @Override public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (ScatterShape i : mShapes) {
            switch(i.mShape){
                case 0:
                canvas.drawRect(i.mX - mRadius, i.mY - mRadius, i.mX + mRadius, i.mY + mRadius, itemColor);
                break;
                case 1:
                Path path = new Path();
                path.moveTo(i.mX - mRadius, i.mY - mRadius);
                path.lineTo(i.mX, i.mY + mRadius);
                path.lineTo(i.mX + mRadius, i.mY - mRadius);
                path.lineTo(i.mX - mRadius, i.mY - mRadius);
                path.close();

                canvas.drawPath(path, i.mColor);
                break;
                case 2:
                canvas.drawCircle(i.mX, i.mY, mRadius, i.mColor);
                break;

             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I'm still unsure of how to set this up. I've updated my original post, and removed the declaration of FrameLayout main from the drawPoint method and made it global as edthethird suggested, but it still only displays one item.

Comment: The FrameLayout will just stack your items, unless you give them a gravity. Until that happens, you will only see one item. How do you want your view positioned? Arbitrary locations or in a straight line going down the screen, etc...?

Comment: It seems you want the in arbitrary positions, in that case, with how you have things designed, you will need to use an AbsoluteLayout.

Comment: I believe, though, you could improve the design by making ScatterPoints tiny objects that only contain coords, objectType and colour. Then make a view called ScatterDrawer that draws all of these views in its canvas.

Comment: The only thing I need this to do is display the objects on the canvas, and I will be adding a small menu on the left side of the UI later. Whichever layout supports this I'll use
Edit: I need to support different shapes and colours, so I can't remove the attributes

Comment: I'm not saying remove the attribute. I'm saying put them into their own class that does **not** extend View and instead is just a container. Then make a new View that draws all of your objects. Refer to my edit (in a minute).

Comment: To be honest I don't fully understand your code. The draw method handles all of the objects, rather than my method of passing them off individually, leading to the overwritting. I'm just unsure of how to get it to paint it all. How do you call it from the main class file?

Updated original post to reflect changes

Comment: All you do here is add the ScatterShapeDrawer to the FrameLayout via a mFrameLayout.addview(mScatterShapeDrawer) and that will draw every thing.

Comment: I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around  the idea of movie from scatterPoint being a singular item to handling an array of them in the draw method. How do you define mScatterPoint in the main method and add it to the frame layout?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
public void drawPoint(scatterPoint point) {
    FrameLayout main = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
    main.addView(point);
}
```

Make your `FrameLayout main;` a global variable.  Then, right after you call `setContentView(R.layout.x);` in `onActivityCreated()`, call `main = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);`

You only want to make this call once.  Every time the current implementation calls `public void drawPoint(scatterPoint point);`, the FrameLayout is being reinitialized and clearing all the old drawings.

Comment: Please refer to my comment for @talnicolas.